# How to replace last n characters in the kth occurence of a line containing a certain substring using sed or awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Suppose I have a file that resembles the following format:

```
\\ Random other lines \\
...
27861NA+    NA+89122  13.480  11.554  10.082
27862NA+    NA+89123   2.166   5.896  10.108
27863NA+    NA+89124   8.289   6.843   3.090
27864NA+    NA+89125  12.972   5.936   4.498
27865CL-    CL-89126  13.914   2.125  12.915
27866CL-    CL-89127  12.050  13.907   3.559
...
\\ Random other lines \\
```

I am trying to find a way of replacing the last 24 characters of each line with a string that I have prepared, for the first 3 instances of lines in the file that contain the string "NA+".

For example, my output would ideally look like:

```
\\ Random other lines \\
...
27861NA+    NA+89122  my first string  hello
27862NA+    NA+89123  my second string foo  
27863NA+    NA+89124  my final string bar $$
27864NA+    NA+89125  12.972   5.936   4.498
27865CL-    CL-89126  13.914   2.125  12.915
27866CL-    CL-89127  12.050  13.907   3.559
...
\\ Random other lines \\
```

So far, I have found a sed command that will remove the last 24 characters from **every** line in the file:

```
sed 's/.\{24\}$//' myfile.txt
```

And also an awk command that will return the kth line that contains the desired substring:

```
awk '/NA+/{i++}i==1' myfile.txt
```

Does anyone have an idea about how I could replace the last 24 characters in the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd lines of my file that each contain a certain substring?

Comment: Create a loop to run 3 times with a shell variable that matches the string "NA+" in your file. Also compare the Line count to avoid matching the same line again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single ***awk***:

```
awk -v str="my string" '!f && /NA\+/{ f=1; n=NR+3 }n && n>NR{ $4=$5=""; $3=str }1' myfile.txt
```

Comment: This modifies all the lines that contain the NA+ substring, not only the first 3, and also incorrectly modifies the first three lines that follow the last line that contains NA+

Comment: This is (a sample of) my actual output:

...
27860NA+ NA+89121 my string  
27861NA+ NA+89122 my string  
27862NA+ NA+89123 my string  
27863NA+ NA+89124 my string  
27864NA+ NA+89125 my string  
27865CL- CL-89126 my string  
27866CL- CL-89127 my string  
27867CL- CL-89128 my string  
27868CL-    CL-89129   2.617   4.968  11.497
27869CL-    CL-89130   4.954   3.078   4.030
27870CL-    CL-89131   9.233   3.081   1.208
...

Comment: Ah yes, you were correct all along - my sincere apologies.

Comment: @Ecaloota, that's ok

Comment: @Ecaloota don't you have 3 **different** strings you want to use in the output, one for each of the first 3 NA+ lines? That's what the example in your question shows.

Comment: @EdMorton I did, but this answer suffices

Comment: OK but FYI to do what you actually asked for is completely trivial, it's just a different but almost equally brief awk script. I doubt if anyone will provide that script since you've accepted an answer that does something quite different but as long as this suffices...

Answer (score 0):

```
string="my first string hello"
awk -v string="$string" '{ if ( $0 ~ "NA" ) {cnt++} if (cnt < 4 ) { print substr($0,1,length($0)-23)string } else { print }}' NA
```

Using awk, set a string and pass it awk with -v. Search for strings containing NA and the increment the variable cnt. When cnt is less that 4, print the everything but the last 23 characters adding the string passed to the end. Otherwise print the line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/NA+/{x;s/\n/&/3;x;ta;H;s/.\{24\}$/some string/;b;:a;n;ba}' file
```

This uses the hold space (HS) to keep a count of the number of lines the script has seen of the required string (`NA+`). Once it has seen n (in this case n=3) such lines it just prints the remainder of the file.